# Writting a proof for $\lfloor 4x \rfloor = \lfloor x+1/4 \rfloor + \lfloor x+1/2 \rfloor + \lfloor x+3/4 \rfloor + \lfloor x \rfloor$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am working on an assignment and have to write a proof for the following:

$$\lfloor 4x \rfloor =  \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor x+\frac{1}4 \rfloor + \lfloor x+\frac{1}2 \rfloor + \lfloor x+\frac{3}4 \rfloor$$

I have to do by proof by case I know the cases to be as follows

$$0 \le x-\lfloor x \rfloor \lt \frac 1 4$$
$$\frac 1 4 \le x-\lfloor x \rfloor \lt \frac 1 2$$
$$\frac 1 2 \le x-\lfloor x \rfloor \lt \frac 3 4$$
$$\frac 3 4 \le x-\lfloor x \rfloor \lt 1$$

The problem is I don't understand how I can express this.

Case 0
In this case I know that it would be $4n$ here

Case 1
In this case I know that it would be $4n+1$

Case 2
Here it would be $4n+2$

Case 3
Now the last case would end up being  $4n+3$

Can someone help me express this?

Comment: Your last two inequalities should have $3/4$ and $1$ as their upper bounds.

Comment: @wolfcall,  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite's_identity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to tackle these sorts of proof is to give a name to the leftover bit: $\epsilon = x-\lfloor x \rfloor$. [I'm sure there is a slicker way to prove this, but here's a straight forward attempt...]

Then, for example, in case 1:

$$0 \le x-\lfloor x \rfloor = \epsilon \lt \frac 1 4$$
Clear the fraction...
$$0 \le 4x-4\lfloor x \rfloor = 4\epsilon \lt 1$$
Then
$$\lfloor 4x \rfloor =  \lfloor 4\lfloor x \rfloor +4\epsilon \rfloor = 4\lfloor x \rfloor$$
since $4\lfloor x \rfloor$ is an integer and $0 \leq 4\epsilon \lt 1$.
$$\lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor x+\frac{1}4 \rfloor + \lfloor x+\frac{1}2 \rfloor + \lfloor x+\frac{3}4 \rfloor = 4\lfloor x \rfloor$$
since $\lfloor x \rfloor \leq x < x + \frac 1 4 < x + \frac 1 2 < x + \frac 3 4 = \lfloor x \rfloor + \epsilon + \frac 3 4$ where $0 \leq \epsilon + \frac 3 4 < \frac 1 4 + \frac 3 4 =1$ so all get rounded down to $\lfloor x \rfloor$.

I hope this helps get you started on the other cases! :)

Comment: Can you please explain this line

⌊4x⌋=⌊4⌊x⌋+4ϵ⌋=4⌊x⌋

Comment: btw thanks this helped give me the start I needed

Comment: Glad to help. That line holds because the 4 floor x is an integer and the 4 epsilon is a bit less than 1 so it gets rounded down. :)